# How many times Harry Potter movies didn't follow books?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

I have just learned that [the Elder Wand wasn't broken in eh book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/was-harry-making-a-big-mistake-with-his-plan-for-elder-wand). But Harry broke it in the movie. Perhaps movie makers are jerks or they did that due to marketing reasons (it looks fantastic).

Now I am curious: How many times did the movies not follow the books? Please, list up.

Comment: Also, if you look at the site FAQ, one of the categories of questions that is considered off-topic is open-ended list questions. Not that it's a bad question - just that it doesn't fit in with the state goals of this particular web site.

Comment: The books are so good, I think you should read them to see for yourself. The fact that interesting plotlines and colorful characters that were prominent in the books were left out of the movies is one of my pet Peeves

Comment: @DavidStratton -- I saw what you did there ;) (Two years  later ... )

Comment: @DavidStratton As Slytherincess states excellent pun (I saw it immediately as I do 99.9% of the time as I frequently pun myself). Funny really - a good friend has used that in a couple stories she wrote - a pet named Peeves (but not at all a poltergeist).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a ton. Here's the links, I'll let you peruse them at your leisure:

[Sorcerer's Stone](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone_%28film%29#Differences_between_novel_and_film)

[Chamber of Secrets](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Chamber_of_Secrets_%28film%29#Differences_from_the_book)

[Prisoner of Azkaban](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Prisoner_of_Azkaban_%28film%29#Differences_between_novel_and_film)

[Goblet of Fire](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire_%28film%29#Difference_between_Novel_and_Film)

[Order of the Phoenix](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Order_of_the_Phoenix_%28film%29#Differences_from_the_book)

[Half Blood Prince](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince_%28film%29#Differences_From_the_Book)

[Deathly Hallows Part 1](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows%3a_Part_1#Differences_from_the_book)

[Deathly Hallows Part 2](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows%3a_Part_2#Differences_between_the_film_and_the_book)