# Can wands burn?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

Reading some of the questions on the Elder Wand (in particular [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12593/was-harry-making-a-big-mistake-with-his-plan-for-elder-wand)), I got to wondering why Harry chose such silly and easily reversible methods of discarding the Elder Wand as putting it in Dumbledore’s grave (books) or throwing it in the lake (movie—that is what he does in the movie, right?).

The obvious thing to do would, it struck me, be to light a match and simply burn the damn thing. I mean, it’s made of wood and a hair from the tail of a Thestral, so it should burn just fine, right?

But then, with all the minor and major fires and explosions and singeings that occur throughout the book (even Fiendfyre), we never hear of anyone’s wand catching fire. This might just possibly imply that wands in general have some kind of anti-fire protection built in… or it may be a coincidence.

### Does any canon source ever tell us if wands in general can catch fire? And whether the Elder Wand in specific can?

(And if yes, would it really be so hard to have Harry not be too thick-headed to realise this and just torch the bloody Elder Wand already? I refuse to believe the only reason he didn’t was because Rowling didn’t want him to be seen as a bad teen role model, lighting up a Deathstick.)

Comment: There is good reason to suppose that the Elder Wand is highly resistant to damage. It must have been 700 years old at the beginning of the series, and had been carried around by wizards throughout that period, not ensconced in a case, yet remained intact. Further, the Invisibility Cloak had similar protections (never ripping or tearing), and its provenance was similar. Even Voldemort's Horcruxes could not be destroyed by normal means. Finally, the magic that Dumbledore used on the ring Horcrux left its Hallows magic unaltered.

Comment: Actually, in the movie Harry snapped the wand in half before throwing it in the lake. But indeed, that Harry (and more importantly, Dumbledore) never sought to destroy the Wand is itself good evidence that it cannot easily be damaged. I would also note that putting the Wand in Dumbledore's tomb is quite safe. The true protection on the wand is Harry himself: only if he were properly overpowered by someone else, and his wand taken, would the wand switch allegiance. Merely snatching the wand from Dumbledore's tomb would do absolutely nothing (as indeed was the case for Voldemort).

Comment: other than being sort of quasi sentient a wand physically itself doesn't seem different from any other piece of stick (as it is easily broken by physical force), so yes, they should be burnable

Comment: @Jonah, so an even more surefire way to destroy the Elder Wand would be for Harry to off himself? So that no one owned it?

Comment: @Jonah You could argue that Harry being able to snap the wand in half (in the movie, at least, which I know doesn’t really count) is even better evidence that it _can_ be quite easily damaged. Whether that extends to fire is a different matter. I don’t think Harry is that much protection—just _Expelliarmus_ him and boom, the Elder Wand is yours. And as we know, a powerful enough wand can fix a snapped wand, even in the hands of a mediocre wizard (Harry); if someone who equalled Dumbledore or Voldemort came along, even with a regular wand, they might well still be able to fix the Elder Wand…

Comment: Also, Umbridge cracks the wand in half as well in A Very Potter Sequel...

Comment: Well, in the movie continuity, obviously it can be destroyed! That simply is not relevant to the book. As for disarming Harry, that would certainly work.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to Dumbledore's own notes in [*The Tales of Beedle The Bard*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Tales_of_Beedle_the_Bard), most wands are buried "or burned" with their owners (page 102 UK version).

> The **general practice of burying (or burning) the wand
>   with its owner, once he or she has died**, also tends
>   to prevent any individual wand learning from too
>   many masters.

They must be *resistant* to the fire they create (as are many Muggle gadgets) but they must also be subject to burning if set on fire.

Comment: Glad/surprised there is a canon answer

Comment: Ooh, good catch. I remembered the bit about them being buried with their owners, but not the bit about them being burnt. Now all that's left is to figure out whether the Elder Wand in particular could also burn—a question I fear has no canon answer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - My two cents on this is that it actually isn't that special. As Dumbledore pointed out, it is said to be unbeatable, but has had a great number of owners and therefore switched allegiance many times. In order for that to happen, it needs to be beaten in a duel. So unbeatable wand? Nope! I do think its age and number of powerful owners meant that it was both powerful and somewhat aggressive by now, but not strangely indestructible. And I think Harry buried it out of respect for Dumbledore and his own wand, and the filmmakers had him break it to end the films smoothly.

Comment: Well, it doesn’t need to be beaten in a duel (first owner got his throat slit in his sleep, Draco disarmed Dumbledore, Harry wrestled a _different_ wand out of his hands, etc.), but it has been definitely shown to be beaten on several occasions, yes. I was more thinking about Jonah’s initial point: we see examples of older wands (like Ron’s first hand-me-down one) looking quite worn and the worse for wear, but the Elder Wand is centuries old and isn’t described as looking worn; so it’s logical enough to imagine that it has some extra protective spells (_vel sim_) compared to regular wands.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It might be, yes. And as you say I doubt we'll ever hear the details. Or is it just better looked after than a wand owned by at least two unruly teenagers?

Comment: That could also be. We all know how fond Cedric was of polishing his wand—that could well be a general pastime of lonesome wizards. (\*snigger\*)

Comment: Cedric Diggory and the Over-Polished Wand. Fanfic anyone?

Comment: @ThruGog Having just finished rereading _HBP_, I’ve just realised that there may be a canon answer after all. At Dumbledore’s funeral, after the speech, tall flames engulf Dumbledore’s body. When they vanish, he is encased in his white tomb, so the Elder Wand must have been with him when he burns; but when Voldemort breaks open the tomb, he collects an undamaged Elder Wand, so it obviously didn’t burn. The only problem here is that we don’t know if these flames were actual fire or more akin to the blue (and harmless) flames Hermione is so adept at conjuring.