# What happened to Voldemort's wand after the last book, and does Harry own it now?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, wandlore

Is there any reference about what happened to Voldemort's yew wand after he started using the Elder Wand? Would the yew wand stop responding to Voldemort after he started using the Elder Wand? This does not seem a possibility, as he never really mastered the Elder Wand. However, now that Harry has defeated him in a duel, does his original wand change allegiance, as well as the Elder Wand? Does Harry own four wands at the end of the series (his own holly wand, the Elder Wand, Draco's blackthorn wand, and Voldemort's yew wand)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be assumed that Voldemort discarded his wand.  On page 501 of Deathly Hallows (Scholastic paperback), when Voldemort goes to

> Dumbledore's Tomb to get the Elder Wand,

Voldemort uses "the old yew wand" to split the tomb open:

> "He raised the old yew wand:  How fitting that this would be its last great act."

That suggests that Voldemort was planning on never again using his previous wand and somehow disposed of it.

Comment: how would you do that? Destroy it? Or just throw it away? Or store away in the cupboard under the stairs?

Comment: @user13267 - In *The Tale of the Three Brothers*, Dumbldedore notes: *The general practice of burying (or burning) the wand with its owner, once he or she has died, also tends to prevent any individual wand learning from too
many masters*. Voldemort had the option of dropping his yew wand into Dumbledore's tomb or burning it if he cared about no one else getting hold of it. Just a couple of options to consider.

Comment: Personally I didn't see the thoughts of Voldemort to be an indication of his intentions to dispose of the wand. It is obvious that the yew wand won't be used anymore once he has a better one, but that doesn't necessarily imply that it will be destroyed.

Comment: Why would he need to destroy the wand? I mean, if a mob boss buys himself a new gun, he doesn't destroy the last one. Just put it on a shelf, no?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there is no further reference to Voldemort's yew wand after he takes control (ostensibly) of the Elder Wand in *Deathly Hallows*, or in the epilogue. Technically, the yew wand *could* have continued to respond to Voldemort, even though Voldemort began using the Elder Wand as his main wand. Mr. Ollivander explains this to Harry in *Deathly Hallows*:

> ‘A person can still use a wand that hasn’t chosen them, though?’ asked Harry.
>   ‘Oh yes, **if you are any wizard at all you will be able to channel your magic through almost any instrument**¹. The best results, however, must always come where there is the strongest affinity between wizard and wand. These connections are complex. An initial attraction, and then a mutual quest for experience, the wand learning from the wizard, the wizard from the wand.’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 399 - Bloomsbury - chapter 24, *The Wandmaker*</sub>

Voldemort's yew wand *could* have changed its allegiance to Harry when Harry defeated Voldemort in their final duel, but there is also the possibility that it might not bend its will to Harry.

> ‘Subtle laws govern wand ownership, but **the conquered wand will usually bend its will to its new master**.’ -- Ollivander to Harry in *Deathly Hallows*.
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 399 - Bloomsbury - chapter 24, *The Wandmaker*</sub>

Does Harry own four wands by the end of the series? I assume you're asking whether Harry controls and has the allegiance of all four wands by the end of the series, so I will say that he possibly does. Maybe even probably does. However, this specific point is not addressed in the books or in any Potter article or JKR interview that I'm aware of (Which means information may exist, I just haven't read it.). So I think we have to go back to what canon does say about wandlore and try and put the pieces of the puzzle together.

Perhaps a semi related question: [Could Harry have given Draco Malfoy his wand back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/could-harry-potter-have-given-draco-malfoys-wand-back)

<sub>¹The word "instrument", I believe, refers to wands and wands only -- wands as instruments. I don't parse the text as meaning a wizard can channel magic through any random object. YMMV.</sub>

Comment: Instrument probably implies any instrument capable of channeling magic. Perhaps theoretically there are other instruments that can channel magic besides wands, which just aren't explained in the books due to lack of proper context. For example, it is even possible to channel magic through the wizards body alone (wandless magic). Perhaps it is theoretically possible to channel magic if you only have the core's material, instead of the whole wand

Comment: @user13267 - Definitely not arguing or debating it. While what you say may certainly be true, debate and theorizing isn't encouraged here. So people can take it or leave it. Know what I mean? :)

Comment: looking at your reputation and badges I don't think any one would dare argue with you. These were just some ideas I had about the topic. Just sharing ^_^

Comment: Oh, it's not that -- if someone wants to debate something with me (or anyone else) I'm truly happy to discuss theory in the chat room. It's just the questions I try and keep grounded in canon. Badges, reputation ... big deal! We're all equal fans here and I specifically remember being super excited when I was new to SE and I earned 81 points :)

Comment: A great answer, covers **all three** parts of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

The yew wand is not further mentioned anywhere after Voldemort started using the Elder Wand.

I assume that Harry did not win its allegiance since the wand itself was never defeated or removed from its original master against his wishes. It still belonged to Voldemort even after his death but I assume its power might have died or would die in due time since its master was never defeated with this particular wand in hand.

Harry, owned 3 wands at the end of the series

1. His own Holly wand
2. The Elder Wand
3. Draco's Hawthorn wand