# Was Harry the master of three wands after escaping from Malfoy Manor?

Tags: harry-potter

He was already owner of his original phoenix wand which had broken. As later we come to know he defeated Malfoy so he became the master of the Elder wand. Did he also become the master of the hawthorn wand?

I ask this because [Could Harry Potter Have Given Draco Malfoy's Wand Back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/could-harry-potter-have-given-draco-malfoys-wand-back?rq=1#comment13949_8100) suggests that wands are loyal to their original masters.

> “Hawthorn and unicorn hair. Ten inches precisely. Reasonably springy. This was the wand of Draco Malfoy.”
>   “Was?” repeated Harry. “Isn’t it still his?”
>   “Perhaps not. If you took it —”
>   “— I did —”
>   “— then it may be yours. Of course, the manner of taking matters. Much also depends upon the wand itself. In general, however, where a wand has been won, its allegiance will change.”

(from the book Deathly Hallows)

I am confused. Please help.

Comment: Maybe he was a master of a dozen wands. He taught the DA in year 5, maybe everytime he demonstrated the expelliarmus he got the allegiance of another wand.

Comment: @Neeshka I believe they have to be taken with the intent of taking. Since in the DA the disarming spells were done for practise and the wands were returned afterwards it doesn't cause the allegiance to change.

Answer (score 5):

The book canon says that wands are taken over by the new master. So if I beat you in a duel and took your wand then your wand is mine as shown by your quote. The wider Pottermore canon is that the Elder Wand goes to the person who defeats an enemy. So if you have the elder wand and I beat you I get the Elder Wand. Other wands are not as clear cut. 
If I beat you then your wand does  become mine but it will not work as well as my original wand. Your wand will also remain loyal to you so it is sort of like shared ownership. We both own your wand.

In the case in your question when Harry left the manor he owned his own, currently broken, wand. He also owned the Elder wand and he shared ownership of Draco's wand.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer you are referencing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/25288/5930) says only that Unicorn wands "will generally always be attached to its original owner, regardless of current allegiance" and therefore are likely to accept their old owner again if their new owner voluntarily gives it back.  This attachment, however, does not mean that the new owner can't claim mastery over such a wand; it just means that, *if* the wand is returned to the original owner, it will still work well for them.

The fact that Harry successfully claimed the hawthorn wand's allegiance is established not only by his discussion with Ollivander but also in the next chapter:

> Harry looked down at the hawthorn wand that had once belonged to Draco Malfoy.  He had been surprised, but pleased, to discover that it worked for him at least as well as Hermione's had done.  Remembering what Ollivander had told them of the secret workings of wands, Harry thought he knew what Hermione's problem was: she had not won the walnut wand's allegience by taking it personally from Bellatrix.