# How is it possible for a person to retain his own wand all through school?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does everyone's wand still work for them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/why-does-everyones-wand-still-work-for-them)

With all the questions that have been asked about wands switching allegiance by disarming opponents or physically beating them, wouldn't everyone's wands already be mixed up?

- Snape disarms Lockhart during the dueling club
- Also in the second book, Harry disarms Lockhart
- In the fifth book, all of Dumbledore's Army learned how to disarm by practicing on each other, presumably with a different partner each time
- Lupin disarms Ron, Hermione, and Harry when in the Shrieking Shack

And I'm sure there are more examples that I haven't thought of.

Comment: I was under the impression that only the Elder Wand switched allegiance like that, and that a normal wand stays fairly loyal to the witch or wizard it has chosen.

Comment: @NorbyTheGeek -- Any wand can switch allegiance if legitimately won. How else could Harry have mastered the Elder Wand by taking Draco Malfoy's regular hawthorn wand?

Comment: @Slytherincess, because the mastery is of the wizard, not the wand he happens to be holding.

Comment: @Martha - "if legitimately won" means mastering the other wizard. After all, wands don't duel by themselves or take each other by force. :)

Answer (score 11):

JKR has said that in order for one to master another's wand -- i.e. win it away from them and become that new wand's master -- the two individuals in question must be engaged in a bonafide duel, where they are actually fighting against each other.

Practicing Expelliarmus and even plain old disarming doesn't count.

There has to be a certain intention involved, to master another's wand.

I'd give you a quote, but The Leaky Cauldron is down! I'll see if I can find it somewhere else. **ETA:** I can't find the quote I want, but will update this as soon as I can. I won't link you to the HP Wiki because my experiences with the reliability of all the wiki's material are not consistent. YMMV, of course.